# Eternal error java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC

Tags: java, serialization

I've searched the forum and tried different approaches and I'm still getting this error. What happens is that it will only read one value in the inputstream and then the program shuts down and I get the error. I don't understand why it won't work.

This is the code:

```
public void readRecords() {
    Players records;

    try { // input the values from the file
        Object obj = null;
        while (!(obj = (Players) input.readObject()).equals(null)) { //line 60
            records = (Players) obj;
            myArr.add(records);

            System.out.printf("DEBUG: %-10d%-12s\n", records.getScores(), records.getName());
        }
        input.close();
    } // end try
    catch (EOFException endOfFileException) {
        return; // end of file was reached
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) {
        System.err.println("Unable to create object.");
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        System.err.println("Error during reading from file.");
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
Error during reading from file.
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at hangman.FileReadWriter.readRecords(FileReadWriter.java:60)
at hangman.Game.menu(Game.java:127)
at hangman.Game.findLetterAndPrintIt(Game.java:57)
at hangman.Game.displayMenu(Game.java:31)
at hangman.HangmanTets.main(HangmanTets.java:10)
```

Someone got any ideas?

Comment: "Eternal"? Looks like you're not expecting the problem to be fixed :-)

Comment: @dmitryginzburg that's right.

Comment: Maybe you can add an example of a program that generates the data you are trying to read?